# Best way to open m3u8 stream in PhoneGap

Tags: android, html, video, cordova

What is the best way to open m3u8 video streaming in a PhoneGap application on Android? I already accomplished it on iphone using html5 video tag but it's not working on android as expected.

I'm using build.phonegap.com so I can't use native plugins. When using the  tag with width=100% and height=100% the video gets skewed in portrait. I need a way to open it in the native media player if possible.

Comment: did you find any solution? I am looking for same issue.

Comment: same here. Looks like the media class plays m3u8's audios in Android pretty well buy fails in iOS using AVAudioPlayer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating [my own plugin](https://github.com/louy/PGMoviePlayer).

Comment: Could you tell me how to call your plugin from javascript?